# Split String on ios sdk 3.0

Tags: iphone

I want string array from string according to font and width of label.

Like "This is a boy worked on iphone."

And i have a label of width 20.0 so i need the array according to this in ios sdk 3.0

Please help if any there .

Thanx 
Abhishek

Comment: I guess another way of saying this is: You need to fit a string into a given width. The fit string should be an array. Or something like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use custom labels with font of your own choice and you can use `componentsSeparatedByString` for spliting your array.

Note: Assign it to an array for getting result in array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do here (or if you know it yourself). If you want to know the width of your string to find out if it fits the width of your UILabel, do the following:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font];
NSLog(@"width %f, height %f", size.width, size.height);
```